# max concurrent connection to amazon load balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

My testing shows that amazon load balancer rest connection with its instance when it has about 10k concurrent connections into it. Is that a limit of Amazon load balancer? If not, is there a setting for it? I need to support upto 1M concurrent connections for my testing.

Thanks,

Sean Nguyen

Comment: By "rest" you mean "loses"? Are you sure it's that connection? Have you tried connecting directly the instance at the same time, it is responsive? If it's 1 instance, is it the web server of the instance that's limited?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am experiencing a similar bottleneck and can't figure out how to unblock it.

Answer (score 7):

The ELB should scale way beyond that, *but* you need to be testing from multiple test clients that appear to come from unique source IPs. This will cause multiple ELB instances to spawn multiple instances behind the scenes (this can be detected by DNS lookups). This is explained in the whitepaper that Rightscale published:
http://blog.rightscale.com/2010/04/01/benchmarking-load-balancers-in-the-cloud/

Note that it takes a little while for ELB resources to scale out, so tests need to run for 20 minutes or more.

You also need to be sure that you have enough resources *behind* the load balancer. EC2 instances (as shown in the white paper mentioned above) seem to hit a throughput limit of around 100k packets per second which limits the number of concurrent connections that can be served (bear in mind the overhead of TCP and HTTP). You will need a lot of instances to be able to cope with 1M concurrent connections, and I'm not sure at what point you will hit the limit of ELB; in RightScale's test they only hit 19k.

Also you need to be clear about exactly what you mean by 1M concurrent connections, do you mean total keep-alive connections (assuming keep-alive enabled), or do you mean 1M transactions per second?

Comment: No I mean 1M sockets open at the same time.

Comment: Do you have the ELB in TCP or HTTP mode?

Comment: it is in http mode. And I am using jmeter trying to create 20k keep-alive connections to amazon server.